# Image in first tab header in wpf TabHeader

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism, tabcontrol, tabitem

I want to display an image in a first tab header of a TabControl in a currently fully working Prism MVVM WPF application.

Complete description as follows:

When the user select an item from the Category list in the left region it displays “More Details” and “Related Products” on the right region. This right region contains a TabControl  inside a UserControl.
First Tab shows “More category Details” while second tab shows “Related Products”. Data is shown correctly. Now I want to display category thumbnail and the Category name in First tab header only.

I tried Using a HeaderTemplate on the First tab as follows

```
<TabControl  VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" >
 <TabItem  Name="tabItemCategoryMoreInfo"  >
  <TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image  x:Name="viewImage" Height="20" Width="20" Margin="0,0,2,0" 
                        Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl} }, Path=Content.DataContext.SelectedParent.PictureBinary}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem} }, Path=Content.DataContext.SelectedParent.CategoryName}"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiBold" />
      </StackPanel>
      <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem} }, Path=Content.DataContext.SelectedParent.PictureBinary}" Value="{x:Null}" >
          <Setter TargetName="viewImage" Property="Source" Value="/CatalogModule;component/Images/ItemIcon.png"  />
        </DataTrigger>
      </DataTemplate.Triggers>
     </DataTemplate>
  </TabItem.HeaderTemplate>

  <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="CategoryMoreDetailsRegion" />
 </TabItem>
 <TabItem Header="Products" Name="tabItemCategoryProducts">
  <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="CategoryProductsRegion" />
 </TabItem>
```

It didn’t show the product name or the product image. But it show only default image, so the Triggers looks working. Can some please help?

**EDIT:**

Initially I used the TabItem instead of TabControl in the  image data path:

```
<Image  x:Name="viewImage" Height="20" Width="20" Margin="0,0,2,0" 
                    Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabItem} }, Path=Content.DataContext.SelectedParent.PictureBinary}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Path`s in your `DataTemplate Binding`s are different... that *may* explain why it doesn't work. If I understand you correctly, you say that the `Binding Path` in the `DataTrigger` works, so perhaps changing your `Binding Path` for the `ImageSource` and `TextBlock.Text` properties *might* work?:

```
<DataTemplate>
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Image  x:Name="viewImage" Height="20" Width="20" Margin="0,0,2,0" 
                    Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}, Path=Content.DataContext.SelectedParent.PictureBinary}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}, Path=Content.DataContext.SelectedParent.CategoryName}"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiBold" />
  </StackPanel>
  <DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}, Path=Content.DataContext.SelectedParent.PictureBinary}" Value="{x:Null}" >
      <Setter TargetName="viewImage" Property="Source" Value="/CatalogModule;component/Images/ItemIcon.png"  />
    </DataTrigger>
  </DataTemplate.Triggers>
 </DataTemplate>
```

Just in case you can't see the difference, you were using this in your `Image.Source Binding.Path`:

```
AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}
```

Comment: Initially I used TabItem instead of TabControl, I forgot to mension it, it didn't work. Sorry I didn't explain clearly. What I mean by "dataTrigger is working" is that since it couldn't find the correct picture from the data source(because my code is incorrect) it shows the default picture "ItemIcon.png" from the folder.